# Can we run karate-config .json once while using Karate runner object?

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

I have followed the karate documentation for [callsingle](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karatecallsingle) but that works if we specify the classpath in karate-config.json file. Actually I am using karate runner class like below and I want to run the karate-config json only once for all of my scenarios. I have searched a quite for this but not able to get and not sure even if this is possible ?
Appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!!

```
public class TestRunner {
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:apis")
                .tags("@regression")
                .karateEnv("test")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. Teams are able to use `karate.callSingle()` for specific "one-time" needs and it has been working fine for years.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Peter for quick response!